# Removing action added by a plugin in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook, action

I am using [Popup Maker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-maker/) plugin for Wordpress and I am trying to prevent it to load on a particular page using the functions.php file of a child theme.

I've located in the plugin's directory the file popup-maker.php which contains the following line at the end:

```
 add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'popmake_initialize', 0 );
```

If I remove / comment this line, the popup will not fire, so I guess this is the action I need to remove. I have read the WP codex and numerous posts but still can't get it to work.

Right now I am stuck at this (function I have added in my child theme's functions.php file):

```
function remove_popmaker() {
    remove_action('plugins_loaded', 'popmake_initialize', 0);
    }

add_action( 'init', 'remove_popmaker', 1 );
```

PS: I am using [shopkeeper](http://themeforest.net/item/shopkeeper-responsive-wordpress-theme/9553045) theme and Woocommerce.

All help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are adding a action to `init` which is after `plugins_loaded` so you cannot remove a action after it has run.

you can try the same action but you will have to do this from a plugin

```
remove_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'remove_popmaker', 0 );
```

But i suspect actions added before yours will be run after, this may be unpredictable if not you may have to code a MUplugin (google this).

Comment: is it possible to add the action to a hook called before plugins_loaded ? (in functions.php, instead of coding a plugin just for this task?). Thanks.

Comment: no, if from a theme, it will be after the hook has run, if from a plugin, you could try the function without the add action but if the action you want to remove has not been added yet, it will do nothing. There are no evident hooks to use. But alternatively you could look into the particular functions you want to remove, its rare for something to run at plugins stage, it will normally be add actions for later in the load process.

Comment: Thanks. Telling me I needed to do it from a plugin was the key.

Comment: Good answer. Indeed I have tested that the `plugins_loaded` cannot be invoked in a theme. Useful reference for actions order: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Answer (score 0):

There is a way I managed to do this:

```
add_action('wp', 'disableEmailPopup');
function disableEmailPopup () {
    global $post;
    if ($post->ID === 11625249) return remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'popmake_load_site_scripts');
}
```

Comment: This works for the particular action `wp_enqueue_scripts`. To remove an action `plugins_loaded` from a theme as @David explains is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

@BMM - Without knowing the use case as to why you need to disable the entire plugin on one page its hard to give you the best answer.

For example if you simply wanted a single popup to not show on one page you can use the conditions panel to add a negative condition using the (!) button. Click it to turn it red and you will check for the opposite of a condition, so `(!) Page Selected: Page xyz` would prevent it from loading on that page.

Alternatively you can [create your own custom conditions](http://docs.wppopupmaker.com/article/140-conditions) allowing you to add that condition to any popup.

Lastly if you wanted to unhook it just from the front end you can simply remove the rendering & script handlers

```
remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'popmake_render_popups', 1 );
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'popmake_script_loading_enabled' );
```

And if you want to prevent the queries as well

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'popmake_preload_popups', 11 );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: A common use case to remove a `plugins_loaded` action is to override a purely themed plugin action, and this is probably the OP intention as I understand. Your suggestion is unfortunately not helpful for such use case.