# Remove action from a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

We use a plugin which add a filter to hide some order meta. Now we want to remove them via child theme instead of editing the plugin file. I tried every answer from here but the action is not removed: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240929/how-to-remove-action-from-plugin and [Removing action added by a plugin in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936383/removing-action-added-by-a-plugin-in-wordpress)

**This is the Plugin function:**

```
public function __construct() {
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', [ $this, 'hide_extra_data' ] );
}
```

I tried with that already, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', 'remove_my_action', 1 );
function remove_my_action(){
    remove_action('woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', 'hide_extra_data', 10, 1);
}
```

```
remove_action( 'wp_fwoocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_dataooter', 'hide_extra_data', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'webearth_remove_plugin_filter' );
function webearth_remove_plugin_filter() {
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data',
    array('ClassName', 'hide_extra_data'),
    10 );
}
```

Change **ClassName** with the name of the class used by the plugin, the Class where the constructor is.

Comment: Thanks. I thinks the class is "Commission" or "constructor" but both does not work. How can I prove if it is the right class?

Comment: Class NameOfTheClass {
   public function __construct() {
      add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_get_formatted_meta_data', [ $this, 'hide_extra_data' ] );
}
   }
}

Comment: The name after the keyword Class

Comment: You can check if after the Class declaration you have something like: $something = new ClassName();
In this case, you can try to add: global $something; before the function remove_filter() and change this part: array($somthing, 'hide_extra_data')

Comment: Thanks. But all classes does not work. I'm unsure to be honest if I took the right class or if the function does not work as we want. This is the plugin link: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/dokan-lite/ and in the commission.php file is the "hide_extra_data" key.